# Running "php artisan make:model Flight -mfsc" returns "The "-s" option does not exist."

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-artisan

I'm creating a model using the command referenced in Laravel 8 documentation. The command is php artisan make:model Flight -mfsc
but the command line keeps returning the same output.

**The "-s" option does not exist.**

Do you know why this is happening?

Laravel 8

Composer version 2.1.9 2021-10-05 09:47:38

**Solution**

After running the command **php artisan --version**. I saw that the version I have is 5.4.36 and as it said Brian Thompson, that command is not included in that version.

Comment: Just to be sure, could you run `php artisan --version` and provide the output? The `-s` flag has been around since version 6, so even if you weren't on 8 it'd be surprising if the version was the problem.

Comment: I can't replicate on `8.64.0`.

Comment: Thanks guys,
After running the command **php artisan --version** I saw that the version I have is 5.4.36 and as it said Brian Thompson, that command is not included in that version. Thanks!